# How to check if a checkbox is checked in a check list field in the rendering variant NVelocity template

Tags: sxa, nvelocity

I have a checklist with value(a,b,c,d) in the items.

In the rendering variant template how can I check If 'a' is checked?
I am using Sitecore 9.2

Comment: Could you please add more details regarding where you are trying to verify the checked item and how are you displaying the checklist?

Comment: I have a rendering variant for search result component. Inside that rendering variant I have template and inside that I am trying to fetch the checked items like $item.Fields.Fieldaname.Its working for checkbox field but not with Checklist filed

Answer (score 1):

Note that NVelocity is removed in version 9.3 so if you have other options you might want to use those.

But to answer your question, you could do something like this:

```
#set ($checks = $item.Fields.get_Item("YourCheckListField").ToString)
#if ($checks.contains("THE-GUID-OF-THE-ITEM-A"))
... do your stuff
#end
```

This gets the value from the field, which will be the raw value so the '|' delimited string of guids (in capitals). You can check if the guid of your "A" item is in there.

Comment: I tested like #set ($checks = $item.Fields.get_Item("Zoning").ToString())
$checks it came always $checks instead of value

Comment: Can you edit the question with what you are doing? I tested the code above in a 9.2 and that works.

Comment: Due to secure N/w I am unable to share the details.Can u pls share the field info if possible?

Comment: Thanks .It worked I was providing wrong Field type.Thanks a ton

Comment: Ok - don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue ;)